# Google Contacts + Service Accounts + Python

Tags: python-2.7, gdata, google-contacts-api

I have been trying to write a Python script (Python2.7) to be able to read/edit/del contact information (email addresses) of users in our Google domain.

I am able to write Python scripts using service accounts (Server-to-Server Applications) for Google API Client Libraries by following authorization documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts

However have not found any structured examples that mention how to authorize service-accounts with Gdata apis (contacts api) in my case.

This [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)  redirects to the Oauth2 page to understand authorization however it does not mention how to get it working with Gdata apis using service-accounts.

A sample code to at least read contacts of another user would be greatly helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure on how you can do it with Python, but this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority) might help you. What can I help you is to give this [tutorial](http://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2014/07/06/google-contacts-api-service-account-howto/) that gives an idea on how to use the service account with the Google Contacts API. For more information, check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402294/how-to-access-contacts-api-with-service-account).

Comment: @KENdi I have been through those links before but has been of no help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this after a lot of search:

http://www.itkeyword.com/doc/3465474180866838576/how-to-authorise-a-gdata-contacts-client-in-python